# FLS Create Error

Tags: apex, fls, security-scanner

My code on scanner report gives some FLS Create errors code like this

```
public static cg__SURL__c upsertPublicLink(cg__SURL__c sUrl){

    if (String.isEmpty(sURL.cg__SUrl_Id__c)) {
        String baseURL = (String) SDriveConfigUtil.getSdriveConfigValue('BaseURL');
        if( !baseURL.endsWith('/') )
            baseURL += '/';
        //AS: isCreateable & isUpdateable() are added.
        if (Schema.sObjectType.cg__SURL__c.fields.cg__SUrl_Id__c.isCreateable() &&  Schema.sObjectType.cg__SURL__c.fields.cg__SUrl_Id__c.isUpdateable())
            sURL.cg__SUrl_Id__c = sUrlController.createKeyForSUrl();
        if (Schema.sObjectType.cg__SURL__c.fields.cg__Short_URL__c.isCreateable() &&  Schema.sObjectType.cg__SURL__c.fields.cg__Short_URL__c.isUpdateable())
            sURL.cg__Short_URL__c = baseURL + sURL.cg__SUrl_Id__c;

    }

    upsert sUrl;
    return sUrl;
}
```

They show those type of errors on the report;

```
Object: cg__surl_id__c in file: classes/sUrlController.cls
L 384: sURL.cg__SUrl_Id__c = sUrlController.createKeyForSUrl();
Object: surl in file: classes/sUrlController.cls
L 390: upsert sUrl;

Object: cg__short_url__c in file: classes/sUrlController.cls
L 386: sURL.cg__Short_URL__c = baseURL + sURL.cg__SUrl_Id__c;
Object: surl in file: classes/sUrlController.cls
L 390: upsert sUrl;
```

I don't understand what I did wrong, I believe if clauses for both Line 384 and 386 are true. Should I add or delete or even change something in this piece of code?

Comment: It might be just a [false positive](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233973/checkmarx-scanner-is-usless-for-crud-and-fls-issues-checking)

Comment: As a newbie, how can I be sure that it is false positive. It seems hard to follow which of them accepted which of them are not (there are 80 fls create issues on the report). So, I can't be sure whether it is false positive or it does not fit to FLS create rules.

Comment: AFAIK as long as you're looking for the access checks like `Schema.sObjectType.cg__SURL__c.fields.cg__SUrl_Id__c.isUpdateable()`, I guess you should be fine!

Comment: @codeyinthecloud Should I add some lines like object level security, like; `if(Schema.sObjectType.cg__SURL__c.isCreateable() &&  Schema.sObjectType.cg__SURL__c.isUpdateable())`

Comment: You wouldn’t need to as you are only looking for FLS the field level check should suffice!

Comment: It seems like problem was related to curly brackets. Does not make sense but after some changes I decided that.

Answer (score 2):

Problem was related to curly brackets. In security review, it was expected to use curly brackets for each if-else statements; whether it has one line or multiple lines.